# Can a powershell module unload itself

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script module.  One of the first things it does is some checks to make sure certain required values are available.  If not, the module should not continue to load and initialize.  However, I'm not aware of a way for a module to "remove" itself.  I tried calling remove-module (from within the module) but not surprisingly it did not work.  Is there some other way to have a module unload itself?

I realize this would be trivial to do from a script that is outside the module.  But I'm writing this module to be shared with other users who are not very savvy re powershell.  I would like to not have to include the module PLUS another script and then explain to them that "this is an exception and you can't use the normal import-module, you have to always remember to find and run this other script instead".  Besides that, it wouldn't be helpful in case a user did simply use import-module (as they would reasonably expect to be able to do) instead of using an extra script.

Answer (score 2):

You could throw an error in your module if the checks do not pass - this will stop the module from loading. For example try saving this as Test.psm1:

```
throw "Could not load module.";
```

Try loading this with Import-Module .\Test.psm1. You'll get the error and if you do a call to Get-Module afterwards you'll see the module has not been loaded.

Comment: Hmm, that might work.  But I'm thinking it would only work on code the module runs when imported, not necessarily a way to unload the module later.  For example, if the module runs some code during import and throws, the maybe module wouldn't load.  But if you run import module, then call some function in the module and you find something then that says the module should unload, I don't think a throw will allow the module to unload itself.  Guess I'll have to do some testing to try.  But thanks for an idea to try.

Comment: No, you're right, it will only stop the loading, it won't unload later. I would argue though that perhaps unloading the module is not the best approach - it seems strange that calling a function in a module would remove that function from use! Kind of like knocking on a door causing the house to vanish... Plus of course what would removing the module achieve? You'd reload it, try again and same thing would happen. Maybe it would be better to put the module in a faulted state, so that if you called any of the functions you got an error until the problem was fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an exact answer to your question but it is still a solution. In scenarios like you describe I would go another way. Create an external script (not part of a module) that either checks prerequisites itself and does not load the module at all if something is missing or loads the module always, checks success/failure-something exposed by the module and unloads the module in case of a failure. Then use this script instead of `Import-Module`.